# Using mod_rewrite to access images better?

Tags: mod-rewrite

In my application, my javascript files are in the folder `/web_root/inc/js/`, my images are in `/web_root/inc/images/`, and my css files are in `/web_root/inc/css/`.

I don't like the links, so I thought I'd use mod_rewrite on them. Is it recommended and/or possible to use mod_rewrite, so in my code I could include images, JS  and CSS files just like in the following example:

```
<img src="images/img.png" alt="image" />
```

Instead of:

```
  <img src="inc/images/img.png" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web_root folder add an .htaccess file and include the next rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/inc/images/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I did it and it worked for me.

Hope i help you